# is the second part after && really needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given below is snippet of code from ActiveRecord::Base of rails3

```
 def columns
    unless defined?(@columns) && @columns
      @columns = connection.columns(table_name, "#{name} Columns")
      @columns.each { |column| column.primary = column.name == primary_key }
    end
    @columns
  end
```

I think all we need is

```
unless defined?(@columns)
```

since @columns will never be false if it is ever set

Answer (score 1):

I've gone back-and-forth on this, and honestly it's hard to say without know more about your code.

If it matters whether `@columns` is truthy or not, then you may want to keep it the way it is.

If it's acceptable for `@columns` to be `nil`, then it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Later in the file, there is a method `reset_column_information` which sets `@columns` to `nil`:

```
  def reset_column_information
    connection.clear_cache!
    undefine_attribute_methods
    @column_names = @columns = @columns_hash = @content_columns = @dynamic_methods_hash = @inheritance_column = nil
    @arel_engine = @relation = @arel_table = nil
  end
```

`nil` is a false value in Ruby (that is, both `nil` and `false` will be treated as false for the purpose of `if` statements, boolean operations, and the like). So, setting `@columns` (and everything else) to `nil` is used as a way of resetting all of the cached information, so the next time someone calls `columns` it will be recomputed.

Thus, you do need the `&& @columns` clause in the `if` statement. If either `@columns` is not yet defined, or it has been reset to `nil`, then it will compute and cache the column information.

Comment: But, if `@columns` has not been defined or it is `nil` then `defined?` will return `nil`, right?

Comment: @Zabba No, if `@columns` is set to nil, `defined?` will not return `nil`, it will return `"instance-variable"`.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like some problem with the tryruby.org was causing wrong info to be output. Removed my answer after verifying in MRI.